# How to do OpenCL programming in the newest Xilinx Vivado (2014.2)?

Tags: opencl, xilinx

I used a simple "Hello, world." OpenCL program in the version 2014.2 Xilinx Vivado IDE, which declared its [OpenCL support](http://press.xilinx.com/2014-04-16-Vivado-Design-Suite-2014-1-Increases-Productivity-with-Automation-of-UltraFast-Design-Methodology-and-OpenCL-Hardware-Acceleration). One of the code snippets is as follows:

```
#include <CL/opencl.h>

...

// Connect to a compute device

//

int gpu = 1;

err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, gpu ? CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);

if (err != CL_SUCCESS)

{

    printf("Error: Failed to create a device group!\n");

    return EXIT_FAILURE;

}
```

However, it seems that this Vivado couldn't recognize the header "CL/opencl.h" and the cl related functions. I resolved the header problem by manually put a external CL directory (derived from CUDA SDK) in my current Vivado HLS project, but it still reported errors like "function 'clGetDeviceIDs' has no function body".

Answer (score 1):

`#include <CL/opencl.h>` is how it's done on Mac OS X, but on Windows it is usually `#include <CL/cl.h>`. Have you located your CL include folder? Have you told the IDE where it is? It sounds like your second problem (after you worked around the first) is that you're not linking against OpenCL.lib (or whatever the library extension is on your platform). You need to locate that too and link to it. On an ICD-supporting platform, the Khronos lib can be used and it dynamically locates the installed drivers, but on your platform it is probably be different, so consult the Xilinx instructions.

Comment: I am doing this on Linux, and `#include <CL/opencl.h>` is good, while `#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>` works for Mac OS X. I've solved all the compiling and linking problems for the Vivado IDE in terms of compiling, and csim.exe and csim.sh are generated in the current solution directory, both of them can work if I have a GPU. What blocks me now is the synthesis step. I think Vivado probably should not need any GPU drivers (e.g., that from AMD or NVIDIA), and OpenCL is just a programming model, thus Xilinx should provide its own compiler and runtime support for OpenCL if it wants to synthesize it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that including `clc.h` in my Vivado 2015.2 did the trick.